# Primefaces fileUpload disable executable files regular expression issue

Tags: regex, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 8 fileUpload component, and I have a requirement to disable some file extensions and allow anything else so I tried to use the following regular expression

```
allowTypes="/^[^.]+$|\.(?!(aspx|exe|jsp|xhtml|js|msi|msc|xml|bat|cmd|sh|bash)$)([^.]+$)/i"
```

and I tested it in the regular expression website and it is working fine:

https://regexr.com/

EDIT: allowTypes only works fine with me if used it to validate only against valid types as follows:

```
allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|tiff|pdf|pdf|doc?x)$/i"
```

but when I try to apply it in the fileUpload component, it's not working, and I can upload the above files without any issues.

Comment: Try `"/^(?:[^.]+$|.*\.(?!(?:aspx|exe|jsp|xhtml|js|msi|msc|xml|bat|cmd|sh|bash)$)[^.]+)$/i"`

Comment: i tried it and got same behavior

Comment: The second `allowTypes` has `doc?x`. This say that the `c` is optional. Thus it matches `dox` and `docx` which may not be what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the [source code](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/8f1e27bcaae708477d92a80a50e1ade193d2efd0/src/main/java/org/primefaces/util/FileUploadUtils.java#L160), they seem to check on the content-type or the filename, not just the extension. When there is a match in filename or content-type, the file is accepted. Maybe it is worth trying to match the full filename, while at the same time making sure that the content-type does not match, for example:

```
.*\.(?!(aspx|exe|jsp|xhtml|js|msi|msc|xml|bat|cmd|sh|bash)$)([^.]+$)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want capturing for next use the group with extension file use this:

```
^[^.]*$|^.*\.(?!(?:aspx|exe|jsp|xhtml|js|msi|msc|xml|bat|cmd|sh|bash)$)[^.]*$
```

else use this:

```
^[^.]*$|^.*\.(?!(?:aspx|exe|jsp|xhtml|js|msi|msc|xml|bat|cmd|sh|bash)$)([^.]*)$
```

With this syntax, any file that does not end with the listed extensions is accepted in its full length, even a file of length 0.

If the file must contain at least one character use this:

```
^[^.]+$|^.*\.(?!(?:aspx|exe|jsp|xhtml|js|msi|msc|xml|bat|cmd|sh|bash)$)([^.]*)$
```

For debug these solutions use https://regex101.com/